# Swing Flatlaf customized properties file

Tags: java, maven, swing, look-and-feel, flatlaf

I have integrated the flatlaf look and feel library into my Swing application via Maven, specifically utilizing version 1.6.2 of FlatLaf.

Within my application, I've employed the existing theme named "flatlaflight.setup()". However, prior to this step, I introduced a properties file bearing the same name into the resources directory. This file was utilized to tailor the style parameters according to my requirements. Regrettably, the system is unable to retrieve the customizations specified within this properties file.

Registered the custom default source to FlatLightLaf.registerCustomDefaultsSource("src/main/resources");
also tried
FlatLightLaf.registerCustomDefaultsSource("resources");

Comment: Don't use `src/main` or `src/main/resources` or `resources`, these paths won't exist at runtime. First, I would recommend, creating a directory under resources (name it what ever you like), place your properties file in it and then use that directory name instead, for example `FlatLightLaf.registerCustomDefaultsSource("setup");`, where `setup` is the name of directory.  If you have subdirectories, then you need to use `.` to seperate them, for example `path.to.your.properties.file`

Comment: The contents of the `resources` directory will be copied into your resulting application bundle (excluding the `resources` directory name itself), so a resource named `src/main/resources/image.png`, will appear to your application as `/image.png` and can accessed by using `Class#getResource` or variants.  This is standard maven practice and I would suggest spending some time to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a FlatLaf properties file in a Maven project:

1. The properties file name must match the used theme class name. E.g. `FlatLightLaf.properties` for class `FlatLightLaf` or `FlatDarkLaf.properties` for class `FlatDarkLaf`.
2. Place the properties file under the Maven `resources/themes` folder (relative path: `src/main/resources/themes`).
3. You must call the method below **BEFORE** setting the look and feel:

```java
FlatLaf.registerCustomDefaultsSource("themes"); // look for properties file in themes folder

// setup theme later
```

Note: A [section of the documentation](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/how-to-customize/#new_theme) places the properties file in `com/myapp/themes/MyDarkerLaf.properties` which I don't recommend for a Maven project because your properties will be deleted when you generate a jar file for your program.

#### Reference

https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/how-to-customize/#application_properties